# Using direct query, I want to show consecutive data for last three days and today at the same hour of time in a Table visual in MS Power BI

Tags: powerbi

Using direct query,I want to show a table visual with today's data and last 3days data available at the same hour of time. Attached is the requirement, is there any way to achieve this.

[image]

Comment: Where from you are getting the Time?

Comment: I have fixed this by modifying the sql query, from there i am getting the hour.

Answer (score 0):

I tried modifying the sql query viz. direct mode and created table visual running a separate sql query. select datepart function in sql. eg.DATEPART(HOUR,GETDATE())

Comment: Yes It worked. Right now I am not facing the issue. Modified the sql query.